# screeps: conditions won't work - clueless

Tags: javascript, screeps

So i have been trying this to automatically spawn Creeps in percentage to total living creeps.
however when i run this, it just keeps on spawning harvesters, completely ignoring the conditions even though console.log returns the expected results .

and now i'm clueless about what is going wrong

```
//creepManager.creations() == counts total creeps and spawns creeps in function of total
    var spawnCreep = require('spawnCreep');
    var counter = require('counter');
    exports.creations=function(){

    if(  counter.guardCount()/counter.totalCount()<0.5 && counter.harvesterCount()>1){

        spawnCreep.guard();

    } else if (counter.harvesterCount()/counter.totalCount()<0.3){

        spawnCreep.harvester();

    } else if(counter.builderCount()/counter.totalCount()<0.2){

        spawnCreep.builder();
    } else {
        spawnCreep.guard(); //default
    }
};  // 5guards, 3harvesters, 2 builder per 10CREEPS`
```

(spawnCreep is another module which keeps track of how the creepers are build)

Comment: What does your counter look like? Are you checking memory? Memory keeps creatures in it even if they are dead and there are also queued creatures in, that may never be built (depending on your code). I have a similar setup, and have similar issues. However I get them to run ok, but after a while they no longer spawn...

Comment: We'll need to know what counters methods are doing first.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar in my old code:

```
function allocateResources() {
    var counts = {guard : 0, healer : 0}
    for (var name in Game.creeps) { 
        if (name.indexOf("guard") > -1) {
            counts["guard"]++;
        } else if (name.indexOf("builder") > -1) {
            counts["builder"]++;
        }
        // ...
        counts["total"]++;
    }

    if (counts["guard"] / (counts["total"] + 1) < 0.51) {
       spawnCreep("guard"); 
    } else if (counts["builder"] / (counts["total"] + 1) < 0.34) {
       spawnCreep("builder");
    } 
    // ...
}
```

You should make sure that you avoid division by zero, perhaps that's the bug for you.