# Screeps: Why does the Memory tab no longer update?

Tags: javascript, screeps

The memory seems to still be reading and writing correctly, but the memory tab always shows the initial state, as though there were no creeps or spawns in the room. It wasn't like this a couple days ago. What do I do? The problem exists in Firefox and Chrome, seemingly regardless of cached data.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue in a website that you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, it is fixed now.

Please keep in mind that it is better to send bugs to contact@screeps.com rather than to post them on StackOverflow, which is for coding questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can click the `refresh' button to the left in order to see the contents of the memory. But I agree that this is a less then optimal way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it's an issue with `localStorage`, [artch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964914/artch) has answered a similar question about these type of issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060388/1814415

You could try to run the game on another browser or maybe clearing the cache on your current browser.

Comment: I've had the issue in both Firefox and Chrome. I just tried closing the tab in Firefox, clearing the cache, and reloading the page, but the issue persisted. Strangely, my scripts were also still in place.

Comment: I opened an incognito window in Chrome, loaded the screeps sandbox, and entered into the console "Memory.test='?';". The memory tab still shows this: "{ "creeps": {}, "spawns": {} }"

Comment: Add this to your question ;)

Comment: I just checked here, I've had the same issue on both Firefox and Chrome. Weird, but the refresh button that Ben mentioned did actually work to check memory contents. Must be a bug caused by the last update.

Comment: It seems to me that Memory in general has an "update" bug in it, regardless of the memory tab visually updating. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137728/screeps-conditions-wont-work-clueless